# How to show current value in EditTextPreference summary (like what ListPreference could do)?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I could list my current selected value using `%s` in the `summary` attribute of `ListPreference`

```
<ListPreference
        android:key="my_list_setting_key"
        android:title="Just title"
        android:summary="My current selected value: %s"
        android:dialogTitle="My title"
        android:entries="@array/my_list_setting_entries_key"
        android:entryValues="@array/my_list_setting_entries_value"
        android:defaultValue="default_value"/>
```

However for `EditTextPreference`, the below `%s` is not working.

```
<EditTextPreference
        android:key="my_text_setting_key"
        android:title="My title"
        android:summary="My current value : %s"
        android:dialogTitle="My title"
        android:defaultValue="default_value"/>
```

How could I list the current value in the `EditTextPreference` summary (or anywhere that is visible before opening up the dialog box)?

Answer (score 1):

Add:`app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"` attribute to EditTextPreference